# Mathematics in LATEX using Python

Tags: python, math, latex

I have a txt file in which I have a set of linear equations in latex format. I wrote  a program in Python to create these linear equations in this format. Now, I want to write a python code to read this .txt file and convert it to pdfLatex.

An example for my linear equations in my txt format.

5 z_{01} + O_{31}  <= 4

5 z_{02} + O_{31} + 2 O_{32} <= 4

Is there any way to write a code to convert it to pdfLatex? Thank you!

Comment: You probably want to have Python call `pdflatex` installed on your system. The easiest way is likely to do that using a wrapper like the `latex` package at pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/latex Otherwise you can roll your own, using a system call with `subprocess`-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the pylatex library you can create both the .pdf and the .tex files. I saved your equations on a .txt file called 'Example.txt'.

Here's the code...

```
from pylatex import Document, PageStyle, LineBreak, Section, Subsection, Math, Alignat, LargeText, Center, MediumText
from pylatex.utils import bold, italic, NoEscape
import re

class Math_LaTeX ():
    def __init__(self, doc):
        #---Initialize---
        self.doc = doc

        #---Get equations info from the .txt file (in this case called "Example.txt")---
        equations = self.Read()

        #---Create LaTeX document---
        self.Create(equations)

        #---Save PDF---
        self.doc.generate_pdf(filepath = 'Math_LaTeX', clean_tex = False, compiler = 'pdflatex')

    def Read(self):
        data = open('Example.txt', 'rt')
        equations = data.readlines()
        eqs = []
        for eq in equations:
            eqs.append(' '.join([line.strip() for line in eq.strip().splitlines()]))
        return eqs

    def Create(self, equations):
        with self.doc.create(Center()) as Centered:
            with Centered.create(Section(title='', numbering='')) as Title:
                Title.append(LargeText(bold('MATH EQUATIONS IN A PDF DOCUMENT WITH LATEX')))

        with self.doc.create(Section(title='INTRODUCTION', numbering='1.')) as Intro:
            Intro.append(MediumText(('In this example, the equations shown above are contained in .txt file called \
             \"Example.txt\".')))

        for eq in equations:
            with self.doc.create(Alignat(numbering = True, escape = False)) as math_eq:
                math_eq.append(eq)



geometry_options = {
        "head": "2.5cm",
        "left": "3cm",
        "right": "3cm",
        "bottom": "2.5cm"
        }
doc = Document(geometry_options = geometry_options, inputenc = 'utf8')
Math_LaTeX(doc)
```

Once you run this code, you'll have both "Math_LaTeX.pdf" and "Math_LaTeX.tex" in the same directory of the .py file.

Here's the resultant file in pdf:

[image: Resultant file in pdf]